Jetpack Compose: Let two Layouts fill the space consecutively
in my layout I have a list with a box underneath.

The list should grow in height when entries get added, when it cannot grow any more it gets scrollable.
The box should fill the remaining space underneath the list. It is always visible, even when the list reaches its max height.

Right now I have implemented it like this:
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray)
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f, false)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
        ) {
            items(list) { item ->
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(vertical = 10.dp)
                        .background(Color.Yellow),
                    text = item,
                )
            }
        }

        Column (
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(10.dp)
                .background(Color.Red),
        ) {
            Text(text = "Bottom Box")

//            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(5.dp),
                onClick = { },
            ) {
                Text(text = "ClickMe")
            }
        }
    }

The first two pictures show the current state, the third picture shows how it should be.
















As you can see, the box does not fill the remaining space to the bottom when the list is not at max height.
The problem is: when measuring the list, it has to know the minimum height of the box, and when measuring the box, it has to know the actual height of the list.
I have tried to put a Spacer with a .weight(1f) inside the box, but that results in the list disappearing while the box covers the full screen.
How to solve this? Thanks in advance!
Dominik
edit: I have replaced the last two pictures to clarify that the space should not be divided in two equal parts. The list should first get the space it needs, then the box gets the remaining space. Keep in mind that the box should always be visible.

Try this code. it will be your third picture requirements
@Composable
fun MyCustomScreen(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
val list= mutableListOf("a","b","c","e","rrr","yyy","ioii","a","b","c","e","rrr","yyy","ioii")
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(10.dp).fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Gray)
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(10.dp)
            .weight(1f, false)
            .background(Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        items(list) { item ->
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(vertical = 10.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow),
                text = item,
            )
        }
    }
    Column (
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth().fillMaxSize()
            .weight(1f, false)
            .padding(10.dp)
            .background(Color.Red),
    ) {
        Text(text = "Bottom Box")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        Button(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(5.dp),
            onClick = { },
        ) {
            Text(text = "ClickMe")
        }
    }

 }
 }


Thanks! With this solution both list and box gets a .weight modifier resulting in two equal parts. I want a dynamic solution where the list tells how tall it is, and the box covers the remaining space.

You have to add Modifier.weight(0.5f) to both children of the topmost Column composable, so they both allocate half of the available height.
And for appending the ClickMe Button to the bottom of the screen, you could add Modifier.weight(1f) to your Bottom Box Text composable.
Result:
Composable preview

Thanks! In fact, I don't want to divide the space in two equals parts. I want the list to be as tall as the sum of all entries, growing with each entry added. In your preview, the list should be smaller.

You could achieve your desired behavior by adding .requiredHeightIn(max = 700.dp) modifier to your LazyColumn composable, with that the list wraps to it's content size with a max height constraint that you define in order to leave a minimum space for your Bottom Box composable.
Full code:
@Composable
fun TestComposable(
    mockItems: List<String>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray)
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .requiredHeightIn(max = 700.dp)
                .padding(10.dp)
                .background(Color.LightGray)
        ) {
            items(mockItems) { item ->
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(vertical = 10.dp)
                        .background(Color.Yellow),
                    text = item,
                )
            }
        }

        Column (
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(10.dp)
                .background(Color.Red),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Bottom Box",
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )

            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(5.dp),
                onClick = { },
            ) {
                Text(text = "ClickMe")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun TestComposablePreview() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            TestComposable(
                List(5) { index ->
                    "#$index"
                }
            )
        }
    }
}


Because compose doesn't allow to measure the same element twice, it makes this question challenging to answer!
The idea to solve this problem is to duplicate the bottom content just to know the minimum height of the bottom composable and then use this information to measure the other composable, and I won't draw the duplicated composable, it's just to measure the minimum height of the bottom content, to get around the fact that compose doesn't allow you to measure the same composable twice.
I create a custom layout for this to hide the complexity from the user, and then you have just to provide your top and bottom content as a parameters to the MyColum composable:
@Composable
fun MyColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    topContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
    bottomContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier
            .wrapContentHeight(), // we need this to override the user fillMaxHeight if it is used (to avoid crash)
        content = {
            topContent()
            bottomContent()
            bottomContent()
        }
    ) { measurables, constraints ->

        val thirdPlaceable = measurables[2].measure(constraints)

        val secondMinHeight = min(thirdPlaceable.height, constraints.maxHeight)

        val firstPlaceable = measurables[0].measure(
            constraints.copy(
                maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight - secondMinHeight
            )
        )

        val h = constraints.maxHeight - firstPlaceable.height
        val secondPlaceable = measurables[1].measure(
            constraints.copy(
                minHeight = h,
                maxHeight = h
            )
        )

        val width = maxOf(firstPlaceable.width, secondPlaceable.width)
        val height = firstPlaceable.height + secondPlaceable.height

        layout(width, height) {
            firstPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            secondPlaceable.placeRelative(0, firstPlaceable.height)
        }
    }
}

And here is an example using the previous custom layout:
@Composable
fun App(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    val list = remember {
        mutableStateListOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5")
    }

    MyColumn(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray),
        topContent = {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
            ) {
                items(items = list) { item ->
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(vertical = 10.dp)
                            .background(Color.Yellow),
                        text = item,
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        bottomContent = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Bottom Box")

                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(5.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        list.add("Item ${list.size + 1}")
                    },
                ) {
                    Text(text = "+")
                }
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(5.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        list.removeLastOrNull()
                    },
                ) {
                    Text(text = "-")
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

Demo:

